# order by case in hibernate criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

```
SELECT j
FROM   Job j
WHERE  status = 1
       AND j.jobVisibiltyLevel != 'P'
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN location LIKE '%bengaluru%' THEN 1
            WHEN location LIKE '%karnataka %' THEN 2
            WHEN location LIKE '%india%' THEN 3
            ELSE 4
          END
```

want to implement this in hibernate criteria